# how do i change an image if i click on a button in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am new to swift. I have a button and 3 images that are saved in the array. What I want is to change the images​ by clicking on the button.

```
let circleArray = ["circle-gray-big","circle-green-big","circle-red-big"]
@IBAction func carbsButton(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Comment: where do you want to set the image, on the button or an image view ?

Comment: @Edk , By seeing your comments below, are you tried my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

Global declaration of the class,

```
let circleArray = ["circle-gray-big","circle-green-big","circle-red-big"]
var index = 0
```

***In `UIImageView`:***

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView! //Global

@IBAction func carbsButton(_ sender: Any) {

 self.index = (self.index >= self.circleArray.count-1) ? 0 : self.index+1
 self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:circleArray[index])
}
```

**In `UIButton`**

Change `Any` in `carbsButton(_ sender: Any)` to `carbsButton(_ sender: UIButton)`. After do like below code,

```
@IBAction func carbsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  self.index = (self.index >= self.circleArray.count-1) ? 0 : self.index+1
   sender.setImage(UIImage(named:circleArray[index]), for: .normal)//Button
}
```

**In `UIImageView and UIButton`:**

```
let circleArray = ["circle-gray-big","circle-green-big","circle-red-big"]
var index = 0

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!    
@IBAction func carbsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.index = (self.index >= self.circleArray.count-1) ? 0 : self.index+1

    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:circleArray[index]) //imageView
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named:circleArray[index]), for: .normal)//Button
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:circleArray[index]), for: .normal)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, the only thing i have is that i have different images for Image and the button. so i will have two arrays. and when i click on the button, the button should change as well as the image but those will be totally different images.

Comment: @EdK , You are welcome,. If you need to change image from two are like this way then use, `let circleArray = Array1+Array2` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
let image = UIImage(named: circleArray[0]) // circleArray[1], circleArray[2]
```

in your action function set button image

```
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Comment: thanks. I would like to change the button image when i click the button. as well ass the image view. Basically one click changes the button and the image view.  I was able to do the image view but how do i change the button at the same time.

Comment: @IBAction func carbsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
  
        if carbsCircle == 0 {
            
            carbsImage.image = UIImage(named: "circle-gray-big")
            carbsCircle = carbsCircle + 1
            
        } else if carbsCircle == 1 {
            
            carbsImage.image = UIImage(named: "circle-green-big")
            carbsCircle = carbsCircle + 1
            
        }
        
        else if carbsCircle == 2 {
            carbsImage.image = UIImage(named: "circle-red-big")
            carbsCircle = carbsCircle - 2
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: circleArray[0]),forState:Normal)
```

You can set various images for various state of the button(e.g Normal,highlighted,selected)

Is this something you are looking for? Please elaborate more if you are looking for something else.

Comment: thanks. I would like to change the button image when i click the button. as well ass the image view. Basically one click changes the button and the image view.  I was able to do the image view but how do i change the button at the same time.

Comment: @IBAction func carbsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
  
        if carbsCircle == 0 {
            
            carbsImage.image = UIImage(named: "circle-gray-big")
            carbsCircle = carbsCircle + 1
            
        } else if carbsCircle == 1 {
            
            carbsImage.image = UIImage(named: "circle-green-big")
            carbsCircle = carbsCircle + 1
            
        }
        
        else if carbsCircle == 2 {
            carbsImage.image = UIImage(named: "circle-red-big")
            carbsCircle = carbsCircle - 2
            
        }

Comment: thanks. I would like to change the button image when i click the button. as well ass the image view. Basically one click changes the button and the image view.  I was able to do the image view but how do i change the button at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to give tag to UIButton

```
    @IBOutlet var btn: UIButton!
    let circleArray = ["circle-gray-big","circle-green-big","circle-red-big"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            see.btn.tag = 0
    }

    @IBAction func carbsButton(_ sender: Any) {
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: circleArray[btn.tag % 3]),forState:Normal)
            btn.tag = ban.tag + 1          
    }
```

Do in this manner you will definitely get what you want..If it solve the problem hit up arrow.