# How to change UIButton's image every time it is pressed

Tags: swift, uibutton

How can I make a UIButton change image from A to B and again B to A, every time it's pressed?

Not as `.normal` to `.highlighted`, but permanent.
I've tried the `.highlighted` method because I can't find the code for permanent, here's my code:

```
func ChangeButton() {
    Button.setImage(A, for: .normal)
    Button.setImage(B, for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: I've tried the .highlighted method because I can't find the code for permanent, here's my code:
func ChangeButton() {
        Button.setImage(A, for: .normal)
        Button.setImage(B, for: .highlighted)

Comment: See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938919/how-do-i-change-an-image-if-i-click-on-a-button-in-swift/44939698#44939698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for mentions of `setBackgroundImage` to Xavier L. from the other answer.
Try the following code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    var buttonActive = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "apple"), for: .normal)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        if buttonActive {
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "apple"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pineapple"), for: .normal)
        }
        buttonActive = !buttonActive
    }
}
```

And your storyboard should look like that: 
[image: Storyboard]

N.B. On Stack Overflow you should perform some actions before asking. Try to include some code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing the backgroundImage because it's scaled automatically, and the button text in front won't get covered.

If it's a custom button, within its initializer:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(*yourfunctoswitchimages*), for: .touchUpInside)
```

... and then that *yourfunctoswitchimages* can just check what the current background image is, and switch it accordingly.

---

If it's not a custom button, add a target to it in viewDidLoad or something. Here's a lot of sample code.

In your viewDidLoad()

```
yourButt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switcheroo), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Another func in your view controller:

```
func switcheroo() 
{
    if yourButt.currentBackgroundImage == image1
    { 
        yourButt.setBackgroundImage(image2), for: .normal)
    }
    else { // ...set image to image1 }
}
```

yourButt would be a property of your view controller of course, that way it's accessible to the viewDidLoad() and to other funcs within it.